# Linq to Sql Update on extracted list not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am having issues updating my Database using linq to sql.
I have a master query that retrieves all records in the database (16,000 records)

```
PostDataContext ctxPost = new PostDataContext();
int n = 0;    
var d = (from c in ctxPost.PWC_Gs
                    where c.status == 1
                    select c);
```

I then take the first 1000, and pass it to to another object after modification using the following query:

```
var cr = d.Skip(n).Take(1000);
```

I loop through the records using foreach loop

```
foreach (var _d in cr)
{
// Some stuffs here
_d.status = 0;
}
```

I then Call SubmitChanges

```
ctxPost.SubmitChanges();
```

No Record gets updated

Comment: the changes you are making are in the variable `cr`, but you are submitting changes on `ctxPost`

Comment: If there's an exception during `SubmitChanges()`, the entire transaction is rolled back. Are you sure you're not swallowing or missing an exception somewhere? Also, you need to be careful about disposing your data contexts. They're not meant to be created and not properly cleaned up. Use a `using` statement: `using (var ctxPost = new PostDataContext()) { // do work here }`.

Comment: @FahadJameel: The domain objects are automatically change tracked. This code *should* work as-is.

Comment: No exception is thrown, I was thinking that the take on the object may have detached the the items taken from the  object being tracked, but i am a bit confused

Comment: @mayowaogundele: you can check: `ctxPost.Entry<PWG_C>(_d).State == EntityState.Detached;`

Comment: @CORY, i didnt get that

Comment: In your foreach-loop, you could inspect the result of the code I gave to see if that current instance of `_d` is attached or not.

Comment: I cannot access Entry on ctxPost. It is a DataContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to you all. I was missing the primary key on the ID field in the dbml file.